# About 2d array of character pointers

Tags: c

I found the following declaration in my c Book, can anyone explain it:

```
    char *dic[][40]={
"atlas", "A volume of maps",
"car", "a vehicle",
"telephone", "a communication device",
"", ""
    }
```

Here what does the 40 means i.e. which dimension this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dic` is a two-dimensional array of `char*`; its dimensions are 1 x 40.

The 40 is given in the declarator and the 1 is implied by the fact that there is only one array in the initializer.  The full initializer would have another set of braces, e.g.,

```
char *dic[][40] =
{
    {
        "atlas",     "A volume of maps",
        "car",       "a vehicle",
        "telephone", "a communication device",
         "",         ""
    }
};
```

With the extra braces, it is clearer that the implicit dimension is 1.

Each element in the two-dimensional array is a pointer of type `char*`.  The first eight pointers are initialized to point to the eight string literals given in the initializer.

Comment: If the dimensions are 1x40, why not just have a one dimensional array?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually kind of a weird way to initialize the dictionary.

It is a 2D array of `char*` (zero terminated (`\0`) strings).

The dimensions are [rows][columns].

So you have 1 row (determined by the initializer) and 40 columns of strings,

where 8 of them are initialized.

NOTE: Are you sure it isnt char `dic[][40]` (i.e., a list of strings of max-length 40) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there may be error in book, it seems that they wanted dictionary - 3D array:

```
 char *dic[][40]={
            {"atlas", "A volume of maps"},
            {"car", "a vehicle"},
            {"telephone", "a communication device"},
            {"", ""}
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The 40 in your code means the maximum length of characters (or the total length of the string) is 40.

Think `char *dic[][40]` as an array of pointers. Wherein one pointer points to a maximum of 40 characters.

Comment: that would be correct if it is `char dic[][40]`, this is actually a list of 40 strings.